# System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException and more

Tags: json, database, android-studio

> D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
> E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
> D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4006b60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcf88b740)
> D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 3 2
> W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
> W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
> at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
> at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
> at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
> at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
> at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106)
> at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
> at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
> at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
> ... 10 more

---

### Hey i need help I'm trying to run the Android Imulator but the app appears to me error message  "Something went wrong please try again "

### build gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gas.gasmaianot"
        //0c9dab71-428f-4ea1-bd71-4c37942aa649
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '24729128-15cd-4834-b1a2-65c90254f11c',
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.37.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.2'
}
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.gas">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.CommonClass.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <activity android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.OrderDetailsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" /> <!-- Example: Sets all OneSignal notification's accent color to Green by default. -->
        <!-- Add your API key here -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.razorpay.ApiKey"
            android:value="@string/razor_pay_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.RegistrationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.MenuDetailListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.MenuDetailItemActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.BasketActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.CheckoutActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing" />
        <activity android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.ProfileActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.EditProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

        <service
            android:name="com.gas.gasmaianot.Service.NotificationService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2337353105916756~2279901954"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

GsonResponseBodyConverter

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Square, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package retrofit2.converter.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Converter;

final class GsonResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
  private final Gson gson;
  private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;

  GsonResponseBodyConverter(Gson gson, TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
    this.gson = gson;
    this.adapter = adapter;
  }

  @Override public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
    JsonReader jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(value.charStream());
    try {
      return adapter.read(jsonReader);
    } finally {
      value.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add more information to the question, some code and a description. Thanks

Comment: Hey i need help I'm trying to run the Android Imulator but the app appears to me error message "Something went wrong please try again "

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize a JSON from a REST service?